# Merge two collections recursivelly combining duplicates by property

Tags: c#, recursion, collections, merge

Given two collections of objects with recursive structure:

```
Collection1 = [
    {
        Header: "H1",
        Items: [{
            Header: "H1.1"
        },{
            Header: "H1.2"
        }]
    },
    {
        Header: "H2",
        Items: [{
            Header: "H2.1"
        }]
    }
]

Collection2 = [
    {
        Header: "H1",
        Items: [{
            Header: "H1.1",
            Items: [{
                Header: "H1.1.1"
            }]
        }]
    }
]
```

I'd like to make some kind of function to combine those two collection having as the comparison property the one I indicate, in this case `Header`, and that combines their properties so that the result is somewhat as follows:

```
Result = [
    {
        Header: "H1",
        Items: [{
            Header: "H1.1",
            Items: [{
                Header: "H1.1.1"
            }]
        },{
            Header: "H1.2"
        }]
    },
    {
        Header: "H2",
        Items: [{
            Header: "H2.1"
        }]
    }
]
```

As you can see, it checks recursively the object properties and, if a similar item exists (in this case, comparing the `Header` property), it just combines both objects.

I've tried `Union()`, `Distinct()` and so on, but I cannot seem to find the way to achieve this.

**EDIT:** The merge should be done on a "same-level" basis, so only items that have the same header at the same deepness level should be considered equal.

Comment: Any only if the whole tree is equals it should merge? So, if your Collection2 had `H1.foo` instead of `H1.1` it would't merge?

Comment: Yes, it would merge but as the Collection2 would have an item with a different header, it would be treated as a different item inside the collection (so in the result they would coexist: it would have one item with `H1.foo` and one item with `H1.1`).

Comment: Does order matter? Suppose the second collection began "H2/H2.1" before its H1.  How now should the two collections merge?

Comment: Your data structure is recursive, so your merging algorithm should be recursive as well. That means that you need a base case. Can you enumerate the base cases? That is, what are the simple cases that you could solve the problem *without doing any recursive step*?

Comment: @EricLippert Supposing we are passing both collections to the function, first parameter collection should be the one to be taken into account when ordering.

Comment: Are there ever duplicates that need merging *within* a single document?  For example, suppose your first document has *two* "H1" sections. Do they merge together?

Comment: @EricLippert I think that the only __without doing any more recursive step__ is when we're already at the last deepness level, because this means there won't be more items to be compared. I don't know if this answers your question.

Comment: @EricLippert Yes! The condition here should be "merge any element of `this.deepnessLevel` that has `specifiedProperty` equal to `this.specifiedProperty`". So, in this case, if two elements have the same header: yes, they should be merged. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a class that models your items:

```
class Item
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

This recursive function merges the items in the way you describe:

```
IEnumerable<Item> Merge(IEnumerable<Item> items)
{
    var lookup = items.ToLookup(item => item.Header);
    foreach (var grouping in lookup)
    {
        var childItems = grouping.Aggregate(
            new List<Item>(),
            (list, item) =>
            {
                if (item.Items != null)
                    list.AddRange(item.Items);
                return list;
            });
        yield return new Item
        {
            Header = grouping.Key,
            Items = Merge(childItems)
        };
    }
}
```

Let me explain a bit:

- The lookup is like a dictionary except the value for each key is not a single `Item` but instead a collection of `Item` instances that all share the same key (`Header`).
- Each item in the lookup is not a `KeyValuePair` but instead an `IGrouping` and by iterating all the groupings you get all the headers on that level.
- `Aggregate` is used to create a list that has all the child items of all the items in the grouping. This list can contain multiple items with the same header but this is the kind of data `Merge` is designed to work on.
- To merge the child items recursion is used.

To merge two collections you need to call the function like this:

```
var mergedCollection = Merge(collection1.Concat(collection2));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally we implemented a different (and so much more complicated) model, but I tested your solution and it works as expected, so I'm marking it as solved! Thank you again for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following...

Supposing that you have a class similar to this:

```
public class Node {
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Node> Items { get; set; }

    public Node() {
        /* Note that I like to start the collections within the object's construction, 
         * to avoid issues inside operations that manipulate these collections. */
        Items = new Collection<Node>();
    }
}
```

You can use the virtues of the Linq [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.union?view=netframework-4.7.2), using a recursive implementation of IEqualityComparer. Something like that:

```
public class NodeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Node>
{
    public bool Equals(Node me, Node another) 
    {
        if (me.Header == another.Header) 
        {
            me.Items = me.Items.Union(another.Items, new NodeComparer()).ToList();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Node node) 
    {
        return node.Header.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

The main calling of this is:

```
var result = collection1.Union(collection2, new NodeComparer()).ToList();
```

Basically what this does is use the comparison of the Union method, considering the headers of nodes (through method **GetHashCode**), and for each node that has the same header value, the same process is done for your child (through the method **Equals**), and this occurs successively to all levels.

I've tested this solution with a few scenarios, and it seemed to work out fine, but if there is still some situation that does not solve, maybe it's a good way to start.